# Non coder need to download from S3 using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I am trying to download a folder from S3 using AWS CLI and I think the issue I am having is the target folder and what I need to describe to get the folder to go to!

I have all the inital steps in place configure, keys, region and that is all good but its the call and place to deliver to being the issue I think.

```
[aws s3 cp s3://arn:aws:s3:::temporary-bucket-to-restore-website-files/ folder/file --profile pname --exclude \"*\" --recursive]:
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake that you made is, you did not pass the bucket name correctly. You have to pass the S3Uri(s3://temporary-bucket-to-restore-website-files/) not the bucket ARN. Modify your command as given below, and it will work.

```
aws s3 cp temporary-bucket-to-restore-website-files/ folder/file --profile pname --exclude \"*\" --recursive
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html
I hope this helps you!

Comment: do I need to put in the place its going to? and sorry to be a pain but how should that look if I want it do go to a local drive on my mac?

Comment: been working on options if I use aws s3 ls s3://temporary-bucket-to-restore-website-files --recursive and  i am now getting error Could not connect to the endpoint URL:

Comment: It seems you have not configured any profiles. Remove --profile pname from the above command and try

Comment: aws s3 cp temporary-bucket-to-restore-website-files/ /local/complete/path --exclude \"*\" --recursive

Comment: Error: Invalid argument type

Comment: Can you paste the complete  error with complete command you are using? 
In the below link you can find examples https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#examples

Comment: As-MBP-2:~ ammccolgan$ aws s3 cp temporary-bucket-to-restore-website-files/ /local/complete/path --exclude \"*\" --recursive

usage: aws s3 cp <LocalPath> <S3Uri> or <S3Uri> <LocalPath> or <S3Uri> <S3Uri>
Error: Invalid argument type

Comment: You are not giving  the s3 URL again. Use the below one:
aws s3 cp s3://temporary-bucket-to-restore-website-files/ /local/complete/path --exclude \"*\" --recursive

Comment: Also replace /local/complete/path with your local mac destination folder location

Comment: As-MBP-2:~ ammccolgan$ aws s3 cp s3://temporary-bucket-to-restore-website-files/ /local/complete/path --exclude \"*\" --recursive

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/local'

Comment: Do you mean to add the like of this? local/Users/ammccolgan/Documents and if so where do i add this?

Comment: Command is correct. Seems the user which are using do not have access to S3. Give S3 access to the user and try  again, it will work

Comment: thank you so much for all your help with this i have no idea how to give s3 access as the user name I set in iam, the email or the group name comes up as not existing. is there a simple way to give access?

Comment: Thank you for your help with this and just to confirm I have got the issue resolved, again many thanks for your help,